# что за чудо терминал_))

Tags: linux, unix, консоль

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

что это и реально ли это вообще ?

Comment: А чего нереально, тот же терминатор к примеру. Там можно сколько угодно окон открывать. Кстати, очень удобный. 6 окон и дерево, не так уж и много

Comment: меня интересует именно ЭТО я такого никогда не видел, много окон и я открываю когда работаю , частенько, но что это такое вот это вопрос для меня

Comment: Глянь "терминатор". Может кто-то с конкретно этим (на скрине) работал. Надо ждать нужного человека или тут остаётся только гадать

Comment: Если увеличить фото, там указано что оболочка zsh, это уменьшит круг поиска

Comment: терминатор явно не то

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Это [herbstluftwm](https://herbstluftwm.org) - тайловый оконный менеджер. Терминал тут не имеет значения.

У него есть брат-близнец - [i3wm](https://i3wm.org), который я бы больше советовал, если вы таким интересуетесь. Он более гибкий и функциональный.

Comment: круто спасибо !

Comment: угу. банальный vim [умеет много гитик](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8352699/4827341). рассмотрите внимательнее приложенную там картинку.